# LVM Second Logical Extents is Missing

Tags: linux, lvm, diskmanagement

Edit 1: Just to clarify no data was written to the new extents. I know this because the admin grew the file system with fdisk right after doing the lvextend, he then rebooted for the changes to take affect. Upon reboot the new block device was lost.

Here is what the sys admin did.

A new block device was added, he then added the new block device to an existing volume group, and then he decided to do a lvextend on the volume group:

```
vgextend archive1-retain /dev/sdd1
lvextend -l +31 /dev/archive1-retain/data
```

Essentially extending the volume group with the new physical volume. He then rebooted and somehow lost the new physical volume member (sdd1). However the logical volume mounts and all of the data looks intact.

I am positive nothing actually wrote any data to the volume group after the second logical extent (sdd1) was accidentally added. Here is what I am left with, notice the unknown (missing) device on the second logical extent, which is to be expected:

```
archive1:~ # lvdisplay -am
  /dev/archive1-retain/data: read failed after 0 of 512 at 4400059711488: Input/output error
  /dev/archive1-retain/data: read failed after 0 of 512 at 4400059768832: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid W0btGW-Zp3R-yoAC-dkow-PabM-1Vri-3VUQo1.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/archive1-retain/data
  VG Name                archive1-retain
  LV UUID                fLG6tU-6tla-h49c-KOf2-LIAh-uIFy-wH0XB5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time archive1, 2015-06-12 11:50:30 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4.00 TiB
  Current LE             65566
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     1024
  Block device           253:3

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extent 0 to 65534:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda
    Physical extents    0 to 65534

  Logical extent 65535 to 65565:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     unknown device
    Physical extents    0 to 30
```

Here is what I tried. Looking back I shouldn't have used the --force, but luckily the volume was mounted at the time:

```
archive1:~ # vgreduce archive1-retain --removemissing
  /dev/archive1-retain/data: read failed after 0 of 512 at 4400059711488: Input/output error
  /dev/archive1-retain/data: read failed after 0 of 512 at 4400059768832: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid W0btGW-Zp3R-yoAC-dkow-PabM-1Vri-3VUQo1.
  WARNING: Partial LV data needs to be repaired or removed.
  There are still partial LVs in VG archive1-retain.
  To remove them unconditionally use: vgreduce --removemissing --force.
  Proceeding to remove empty missing PVs.

archive1:~ # vgreduce archive1-retain --removemissing --force
  /dev/archive1-retain/data: read failed after 0 of 512 at 4400059711488: Input/output error
  /dev/archive1-retain/data: read failed after 0 of 512 at 4400059768832: Input/output error
  Couldn't find device with uuid W0btGW-Zp3R-yoAC-dkow-PabM-1Vri-3VUQo1.
  Removing partial LV data.
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
  Unable to deactivate archive1--retain-data (253:3)
  Unable to deactivate logical volume "data"
```

Some additional info:

```
archive1:~ # lsblk
NAME                                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO MOUNTPOINT
xvdb                                     202:16   0   249G  0
└─xvdb1                                  202:17   0   249G  0 /var/log/retain-tomcat7
xvda                                     202:0    0    80G  0
├─xvda1                                  202:1    0     2G  0 [SWAP]
└─xvda2                                  202:2    0    78G  0 /
sda                                        8:0    0     4T  0
└─archive1--retain-data (dm-3)           253:3    0     4T  0 /var/opt/beginfinite/retain
sdc                                        8:32   0   750G  0
└─gwsystem-data (dm-0)                   253:0    0   750G  0 /gwsystem
sdb                                        8:16   0     1T  0
└─archive1--sql-data (dm-1)              253:1    0  1024G  0 /var/lib/mysql
archive1--retain-data-missing_1_0 (dm-2) 253:2    0     2G  0
└─archive1--retain-data (dm-3)           253:3    0     4T  0 /var/opt/beginfinite/retain
```

The logical volume mounts and is usable:

```
archive1:~ # df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2                          77G   35G   41G  46% /
udev                                19G  120K   19G   1% /dev
tmpfs                               19G     0   19G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb1                         246G   62G  172G  27% /var/log/retain-tomcat7
/dev/mapper/gwsystem-data          739G  590G  112G  85% /gwsystem
/dev/mapper/archive1--sql-data     1.0T  330G  695G  33% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/mapper/archive1--retain-data  4.0T  2.9T  1.2T  73% /var/opt/beginfinite/retain
```

Comment: The messages indicate that some amount of data was written to the now-missing PV. With only 31 extents it surely wasn't much, but that is enough to give you a serious headache. It's probably time to go to your backups.

Comment: @Michael There was no data written to the new extents. I updated my question to clarify why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After unmounting your FS, I would go this way :

Step 1 - `vgcfgrestore -l` to identify with file has the correct lvm metadata (the one just before sdd1 extension)

Step 2 - `vgcfgrestore -f filename` to actually restore the old lvm metadata

Comment: I was looking at doing just this, restoring the lvm metadata, but I don't have any experience doing this and I am unsure of the risk. How risky is this?